# How to automatically add any plugged-in USB-Printer to cups and share it to the network?

Tags: networking, usb, printing, share, hot-plug

> aq

I'm working on a Raspberry-Pi Project: A universal easy to use print server. The goal is to plugin any USB-Printer and broadcast it to the local network.

Now, how can I add this printer automatically to cups, so I can share it with samba?

I already set up a Linux Server environment with samba and cups. I also have a script to run some code, when a usb printer has been plugged in.

The method must work with any newly connected printer, which hasn't been configured manually in any way.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 3):

This used to be really simple, you could just use a device uri like `usb:/dev/usb/lp0`. Unfortunately, this has been deliberately removed. It can be enabled again by replacing just a line that signals failure with the open of the device file, but it requires a recompile of the usb backend.

If you want to avoid the recompile, you can try the `parallel` backend, if that doesn't work, you can always use the `pipe` backend. With the `pipe` backend you can send the print data so a simple script that essentially does `cat > /dev/usb/lp0`.

Then you just need a print queue assigned to that backend, and scripts called from `udevd` that enable and disable this queue on USB connect and disconnect. I seems you already have these scripts. Samba will automatically see the print queue if it is configured with CUPS support.

This assumes that you want to use any single printer. The printers you want to plug in should use the same control language, such as PCL.

If you want more than one printer at the same time, it is slightly more difficult, if you are interested, I can expand on that.

**Edit**

`usb`, `parallel` and `pipe` are some of the CUPS backends. The `parallel` backend is meant for parallel printer ports, using devices `/dev/lp0`to `/dev/lp3`. Using a device uri of `parallel:/dev/usb/lp0` could work, as the device interface should be quite similar. The`pipe` backend is used with a script `pipe:/path/to/script`. The script gets the data on stdin and can do whatever is necessary. In this case it has to send the data to `/dev/usb/lp0`. The `pipe` backend may be a SUSE extension.

To configure Samba for CUPS, you mainly have to specify `printing = cups` in `smb.conf`. See `man smb.conf`.

For `udevd`, place a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the content

```
KERNEL=="lp*", ACTION=="add|remove", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/udev-cups.sh"
```

The script `/usr/local/sbin/udev-cups.sh` can be similar to this:

```
#/bin/sh
QUEUE=queue-name
case "$ACTION" in
  (add)
    cupsenable "$QUEUE"
    ;;
  (remove)
    cupsdisable "$QUEUE"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Nice overview about whats possible in this situation.

Could you explain more on how I can use the pipe backend and how udevd works?
I guess pipe is an alternative to cups, is that correct?

udevd seems like a more reliable way to detect USB plug-in/out. What are the pros and cons about parallel and pipe?
How do I actually configure samba to work with cups support?

Sorry about that much questions

Comment: I added some information.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only if your USB printers are the same Make and Model.

1. Open your /etc/cups/printers.conf file with your favorite text editor.
2. Find the 'DeviceURI' line of your USB printer

   `DeviceURI usb://DYMO/LabelWriter%20550%20Turbo?10238102938120938`
3. Delete the serial number including the question mark (?).

   `DeviceURI usb://DYMO/LabelWriter%20550%20Turbo`

Now your printers can be replaced if damaged without needing to reconfigure a new printer.